# Give id to bootstrap modal with jquery for use in sql query

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where I need to have a "show function" where I click on a button, and then it will show the user information based on the id from the button.

I have this js code

```
$("#brugeridbtn").click(function(){

    var id = $("#brugerid").val();

    console.log( id );

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: { 
            'id': '1'
        },
        success: function(msg){
            alert('wow' + msg.id);
        }
    });

});
```

And this is my form

```
<form method='POST'>
 input type='hidden' name='brugerid' id='brugerid' value='$row[bruger_id]'>
 <button type='button' class='btn btn-info' id='brugeridbtn' name='test' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Open Modal With Form</button>
 </form>
```

Im stuck on how to get it to a $_POST so i can use it in the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the on the button like this

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-info' id='brugeridbtn' data-show-id='<?php echo $row['bruger_id']; ?>' name='test' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Open Modal With Form</button>
```

And then

```
$("#brugeridbtn").click(function(){

    var id = $(this).data('showId');

    console.log( id );

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: { 
            'id': id
        },
        success: function(msg){
            alert('wow' + msg.id);
        }
    });

});
```

I haven't given this a test, but the theory should work

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
$("#brugeridbtn").click(function(){

var id = $("#brugerid").val();

console.log( id );

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: { 
        'id': id
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert('wow' + msg.id);
    }
});

});
```

Now you can use id in your php like this :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

EDIT :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#brugeridbtn").click(function(){

    var id = $("#brugerid").val();

    console.log( id );

    $.ajax({
            datatype : "json",
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sandbox_modal.php',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function(data){
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            alert('ID: ' + jsonData.id);
        }
    });

    });
})
</script>
```

// New PHP File :- new_php.php

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];

$tempArray = array('id' => $id);

echo json_encode($tempArray);

?>
```

Comment: It cannot find the $_POST, btw, its all on the same page, does it matter?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zHhxtQQN - Is the page where it should happen, I just renamed it to sandbox_modal - jQuery is included in footer.php

Comment: I would suggest you to create new file as you are using ajax, you should use code sepration( by writing code in different files). Plz check EDIT section of my ans.

Comment: Alright, but I have like 10 different pages, where I want this function, do i just paste the script tag on everypage and url: new_php.php ? Cause the whole point of it, is not to reload the page, but just open the bootstrap modal with the user information

Comment: yup and use proper naming convention for better understanding :)

Comment: There is something wrong, its says  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on the console.log ( id ); line, And the alert does not come up

Comment: for the alert to work I need to remove the json.parse, but when I alert data, I get all the html/css/js in the alert

Comment: have u seprated all code in new seprate file which should contain only php code in it and not html/css/js code?

Comment: No, Cause I would need PHP on the page where html and such is, or else im not sure what you mean

Comment: if this is so then remove 
$tempArray = array('id' => $id);
echo json_encode($tempArray);
and var jsonData = JSON.parse(data); from js and go ahead with your code, it will solve all your issues

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet there are few things to change, to make all stuff work as expected:

1. Wrap your $("#brugeridbtn").click event handler with **$(document).ready(function(){ ... })**
2. In $.ajax call data object should have right declared property - id without quote marks:

```js
data: { id: id }
```

3. Make sure your test.php is in the same folder and it returns according structure.
   You can't simply expect 'msg' to be js-object (when addressing to **msg.id**). I think better choice is:

   - return json from php (echo json_encode),
   - convert json to object in js (JSON.parse) or change $.ajax dataType param to 'json'.

Comment: How do I return the json from the code? should I just echo json_encode post?

Comment: No, it is a common practice to return an json encoded array from php when dealing with ajax requests, like this: <?php if ($_POST["id"]) { $array = Array("data"=>"This is data string for js"); echo json_encode($array); } ?>. Then in js (in success callback) you will have this data is success callback' param.

Comment: From my code it will be: ...success: function(msg){ var output = JSON.parse(msg); alert('wow' + output.data); } ...